# Error during deployment to azure from visual studio online

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I'm getting this weird error when trying to deploy to azure from visual studio online:

```
Exception Message: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\a\src'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.Activities.FindPackageAndParametersFile.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I'm pretty sure that I am not using a folder named 'd:\a\src' in my solution.

Comment: That folder is the one created by the build service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the `Build Agent Folder` to something that involves `$(SourceDir)`.